# Converting PowerShell to Bash - Az CLI / Azure Key Vault

Tags: bash, azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm not great with bash & have been trying to reproduce this PowerShell code in bash. It's basically querying Azure Key Vault, pulling down the secrets and storing them locally as environment variables.

Can anyone help?

```
$env:KEY_VAULT_SP          = ""
$env:KEY_VAULT_SP_PASSWORD = ""
$env:KEY_VAULT_SP_TENANT   = ""
$env:KEY_VAULT             = ""

az login --service-principal --username $env:KEY_VAULT_SP --password $env:KEY_VAULT_SP_PASSWORD --tenant $env:KEY_VAULT_SP_TENANT

$secretsList = $(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $env:KEY_VAULT | ConvertFrom-Json)

foreach ($secret in $secretsList) {
  $secretId = $secret.id
  $shortSecretId = $((Split-Path $secretId -Leaf).ToUpper())
  $shortSecretId = $($shortSecretId -replace "[-]", "_")
  $secretObj = $(az keyvault secret show --id $secretId | ConvertFrom-Json)
  [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($shortSecretId, $secretObj.value)
}

Get-ChildItem env:
```

This is what I have so far, but it's taking me far too long :-(

It's nearly there; just need to write the values out as variables and test them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Write variables direct.

KEY_VAULT_SP=""
KEY_VAULT_SP_PASSWORD=""
KEY_VAULT_SP_TENANT=""
KEY_VAULT=""
az login --service-principal --username $KEY_VAULT_SP --password $KEY_VAULT_SP_PASSWORD --tenant $KEY_VAULT_SP_TENANT

# Get list of secret ids from key vault.
secretsId=$(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $KEY_VAULT --output tsv --query '[*].[id]')

for secretId in $secretsId
  do
    # Get secretName & replace - with _ as variables don't like dashes.
    secretName=$(az keyvault secret show --id $secretId --output tsv --query 'name' | sed 's/-/_/g')
    secretValue=$(az keyvault secret show --id $secretId --output tsv --query 'value')
    echo "    Exporting $secretName ..."
    # THIS DOESN'T WORK; ARGHH :-(
    export $secretName=$secretValue
  done

printenv | sort -f
```

Comment: try this code bash command [Bash script to fetch and store secrets from Azure KeyVault · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/shtratos/6c03ba89b302ff9ca6084d9ade627b79)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually sorted ... it required a '\r' on the export to remove a new line suffix on the secretName variable that was preventing the export from working; that was damn hard to figure out :-(

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Write variables direct.

KEY_VAULT_SP=""
KEY_VAULT_SP_PASSWORD=""
KEY_VAULT_SP_TENANT=""
KEY_VAULT=""
az login --service-principal --username $KEY_VAULT_SP --password $KEY_VAULT_SP_PASSWORD --tenant $KEY_VAULT_SP_TENANT

# Get list of secret ids from key vault.
secretsId=$(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $KEY_VAULT --output tsv --query '[*].[id]')

for secretId in $secretsId
  do
    # Get secretName & replace - with _ as variables don't like dashes.
    secretName=$(az keyvault secret show --id $secretId --output tsv --query 'name' | sed 's/-/_/g')
    secretValue=$(az keyvault secret show --id $secretId --output tsv --query 'value')
    echo "    Exporting $secretName ..."
    # \r strips newline suffix from secretName (use 'echo $secretName | cat -ve' to check; ^M is \r)
    export ${secretName%$'\r'}=$secretValue
  done

printenv | sort -f
```